# Change Y Axis vertical line color in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've tried to look after a function that can change the vertical yAxis line color, but without luck.

Which function can I use for changing the color?

[image]

This is the color I want to change, so 77, 78, 79 etc is another color.

Hope someone can help :-)

Comment: Do you want to color the labels or the axis itself?

Comment: Use `tickColor` in the Y-axis category it can change the vertical yaxis line color.

Comment: I've tried this: http://puu.sh/du9Cy/1d6fd8157b.png - but it doesn't seems to react on the tickColor variabel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `style` in `yAxis.labels` for the label colors, and `gridLineColor` for the line colors:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: 'red'
        }
    },
    gridLineColor: 'red'
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fehjnp5a/1/